# In SFMC's Journey Builder Custom Activity, how do I register a contact as not processed in the /execute endpoint?

Tags: journeybuilder, custom-activity

I have a custom activity created and have configured it to hit the */execute* endpoint which I wrote. When I activate the journey, I get hits to the */execute* endpoint. However, in the */execute* endpoint, I have certain conditions, failing which the contact should not be processed further in that particular custom activity or the journey itself. I tried sending responses with status 400 and 500, but neither of them worked, with the custom activity showing they were a "***Success***", albeit with the Status Details showing ***500***. How do I make it show up as a **Soft Error / Hard Error**, so that the marketer can know something is wrong with that particular contact record?[image]